# String to Integer solution in Java

Tags: java, string

I have found this solution of `String` to `int` conversion in Java (Source: *"Elements of programming interviews in Java"*). Can anyone tell me what is going on?

```
public static int stringToInt(String s){
  return (s.charAt(0) == '-' ? -1 : 1) * s.substring(s.charAt(0) == '-' ? 1 :0)
          .chars()
          .reduce(0, (runningSum,c) -> runningSum * 10 + c -'0');
}
```

I understand the first part, where they check if the `String` starts with a '`-`', if yes they multiply the result by `-1` and take only the substring without the '`-`'. What then? Why do they use `.chars()`? In the third and last line, I don't even understand the syntax.
A step by step output would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you pasted it into your IDE and analyzed the return types of these method calls? It would shed a lot of light on it.

Comment: Why would you not just use `Integer.parseInt("yourStringHere")`?

Comment: in the excercise,  Integer.parseInt can not be used. I have also tried to compile it and understand it step by step, but I really have problems with it.

Comment: In addition to @MarkoTopolnik's suggestion of seeing what the methods do, a few Extract Local Variable refactorings with help by giving names to concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why do they use .chars()?*

Because you need to access each char if you want to manually convert the String to an int. Each char contains one digit of the number, so you need to access every char. [`String.chars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) returns a stream of the chars in the String.

*In the third and last line, I don't even understand the syntax.*

Let's break it down, then:

[`Stream.reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) *reduces* the values inside the stream down to one single value, using `0` as *identity* value and the *lambda expression* `(runningSum,c) -> runningSum * 10 + c -'0'` as *accumulator*.

The lambda expression `(runningSum,c) -> runningSum * 10 + c -'0'` gets turned into a [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) instance by the Java compiler. This particular instance accepts two int arguments and will return one int result. You can imagine it looking something like this:

```
class CompilerGeneratedBinaryOperator implements BinaryOperator<int> {
    public int apply(int runningSum, int c) {
        return runningSum * 10 + c -'0';
    }
}
```

The *reduce* method will then call this method in a loop over all the chars in the String, always using the last result as the next `runningSum` parameter (and the *identity* `0` in the very first call).

Now let's look at the statement inside the lambda: `runningSum * 10 + c -'0'`.

What happens here is, it makes use of the ASCII code of each character. It basically assumes that it has a String that represents a valid integer, i.e. all chars are within `'0'` to `'9'`. If you look up an ASCII table you will note that the integer representation of the number characters are `48` to `57`. Thus `'0'` is equal to `48`, meaning that when the character `c` is `'0'`, it's value is `48` and `c - '0'` will be `48 - 48`, which is `0`. If `c` is `'1'`, `'1' - '0'` will be `1` and so on. Basically `c - '0'` gives the integer value that corresponds to the digit represented by the character.

The rest is simple. It will multiply each last result by `10` and add the current digit, which as stated in [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51326677/9199167) works like this:

```
Step 1. 0
Step 2. (0 * 10) + 1 == 1
Step 3. (1 * 10) + 2 == 12
Step 4. (12 * 10) + 3 == 123
```

Answer (score 3):

This is streaming syntax. string.chars().reduce(...) is roughly equivalent to

```
int runningSum = 0;
for (int i = string.length() - 1; i >= 0; i ++){
    runningSum *= 10;
    runningSum += string.charAt(i) - '0';
}
```

You can read more about it here: http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

Answer (score 2):

What they do is start with an initial sum of 0, and then, for each character starting with the leftmost one, multiply the current sum by 10 and add the numeric value of the current character:

For example, "123":

```
Step 1. 0
Step 2. (0 * 10) + 1 == 1
Step 3. (1 * 10) + 2 == 12
Step 4. (12 * 10) + 3 == 123
```

The `reduce` method operates on a stream to produce a single value of some type `T` (in this case `int`), given an accumulator.
The accumulator in this case is provided as the lambda expression `(runningSum,c) -> runningSum * 10 + c -'0'` (following the form `(arguments) -> expression`).

The `chars` method is used simply to obtain a stream from the part of the string after the `'-'`, which you need in order to be able to use `reduce`.

Subtracting `'0'` is used to convert from characters to the corresponding numeric values. If you subtract `'0'` from `'0'` you get 0; if you subtract `'0'` from `'1'` you get 1, and so on.

Comment: yes I understand the idea, my problem is mainly with the syntax. Why should I use .char(), what is the -> operator doing, what does -'0' mean ?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part you are right, you multiply by -1 if '-' is present, then take the other part of the string (eg for "-25" you have "25").

Then you convert it to a char array (IntStream actually but it's roughly equal to a char array) with ".chars".

Then, you take every number with the reduce, which take every character in the array and apply the lambda (the strange "->" notation).

You remove '0' from each char to have the int value (ASCII code of '0' is 48), multiply the actual sum by 10 then add the value of the current char.
For exemple with -420 you have:

- 1) The minus sign (=> multiply by -1)
- 2) The char array [52, 50, 48] (because the char '4' is 52 in the ASCII table, '2' is 50...)
- 3) The reduce:
- - 3.1) 52 - 48 = 4
- - 3.2) 4*10 + (50-48) = 40 + 2 = 42
- - 3.3) 40*10 + 2*10 + (48-48) = 400 + 20 + 0 = 420
- - 3.4) multiply the solution by -1 = -420 *(comes from step 1)*

note: sorry for my poor english, if you don't understand something I said feel free to ask